# How can I "snapshot" an Ubuntu Server installation and deploy it to multiple other machines

Tags: ubuntu-server, snapshot, cloning

I am a web developer and frequently have to set up and configure virtual machines and dedicated machines (almost always on Ubuntu Server installations).

I was wondering if there was an effective and quick way to create a template of machine instances and deploy them to new servers so that I don't have to install and configure the same software and settings over and over again. I understand this can be done with a script but it's a bit of a pain to write. I'd prefer to be able to "snapshot" the machine state somehow and apply it to another box identically.

Comment: for virtual machines, simply copy the VM files onto a large usb storage device. for dedicated machines, as long as the machine hardware components are identical, you can clone the hard drive and then fix grub.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much overhead you have, you could investigate VM management systems like [Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/faq.html) or [Chef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_%28software%29). It has a much steeper learning curve than just cloning VMs, but scales more easily once you have more than a handful of configurations.